# Take a screenshot and got only blackimage after 30 min delay

Tags: windows, batch-file, screenshot

i have a script that takes screenshots every x minutes, and in given moment after 30 min of inactivity, the screenshot takes a "blackscreen" instead of a normal image.
screenshot is black while pc is not active ( not connected to pc by remote , and don't have direct image)

About Settings :
all sleep monitor, lock screen , screensaver etc, are disabled,and performace  optioàns is set to high. do you have some idea what else to deactivate?
my scripts already   simulate a mouse movement every  500 sec , but it doesn't help.

Tools used for screenshot :
screen.exe (compiled from pure c#)
and nirsoftcmd

[image: result_after_30_min]

[image: script_content]